# TestCafe: How to select the first DOM item with a certain class pattern?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, ui-testing

I need to select the first div element whose classes match the `style-[0-9]+ classB` pattern.

e.g.:

```
<div class="style-123 classB">Div1</div>
<div class="style-235 classB">Div2</div>
<div class="style-173 classB">Div3</div>
```

The `Div1` div should be selected in this example.

How to do that in TestCafe?

Answer (score 2):

Selector('div').withAttribute('class', /style-[0-9]+ classB/)

Comment: Or just 
Selector('div .classB')